# Ubuntu 9.04 missing gnome desktop packages

Tags: ubuntu

I removed some gnome related packages from My Jaunty installation. I tried to get those packages from the archive but it looks like my version is not supported. Where else can get just packages enough to bring the desktop up. I am working from the command line for now. I really need to recover the desktop because of the project I have been working on which uses an IDE that I installed. 
Thanks 
Sisa
PS. I used $ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop but couldn't connect to the archive

Comment: This question would fit right in at http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: @WilliamJackson questions about Ubuntu are on-topic for Super User. If a user does not get an adequate answer on Super User, we can optionally migrate it there at their request, but questions which are on-topic [will not be migrated without a specific reason or request from the asker](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2644/migrating-questions-to-the-ubuntu-or-linux-unix-se-sites).

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` and change every instance of these two urls:

```
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/
http://security.ubuntu.com/
```

to this:

```
http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/
```

For example, here is the original line:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty main restricted
```

You need to change it to:

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty main restricted
```

Do that for every line in that file. Once you have saved the file, do

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

try getting another window manager and fixing it from there?

sudo apt-get install lxde

sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop

sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop

any of these

and download the gnome packages from packages.ubuntu.com and install them in the GUI.